# Azure function cannot access connected WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-functions

We are evaluating Azure functions to compare with other solution on the market. We have an Azure function (v2) using .NET Core 3.1 stack. It will invoke a WCF service. It has been tested on localhost without issue.

After deploying to Azure, the function got issue invoking the WCF service ("there was no endpoint listening at `https://dev_service.ca/ourservice.svc` that could accept the message").

It looks like Azure function only can connect to WCF services which are hosted in Azure ?

If we put this WCF service into Azure, I am not sure this will solve the issue or not.

Also, inside of this WCF service, we will invoke call on XRM toolbox to create CRM entity.

I am wondering even if I put wcf into Azure, then, would the connection to CRM instance be the issue again?

In general, how do we allow Azure functions to invoke a call on a WCF service which is not hosted in Azure?

Thanks

Comment: which binding are you using in your WCF? As far as I know, there's no requirement to host your WCF on Azure, I believe it's a configuration problem

Comment: Thank for the reply. The binding is basicHttpsBinding. I am wondering is it possible in the place where Azure Function hosted, there is no connection to this WCF service? AZ function runs well in local.It can invoke wcf without issue. Once deployed, not working anymore.  In local VM, i could reach this wcf service. I have no way to tell the connection from the place holding Azure Function to connect to wcf service. Currently this WCF service is hosted in one VM in the cloud. But is is not in Azure.